# Bottlepy escaping HTML characters not working as expected

Tags: python, escaping, bottle

I am trying to figure out why the bottle's escaping of the html escape character '<' is not working as expected.  I have a large page that has several select pull downs.  It loads a lot faster if I have my page include some JavaScript to set the pulldowns.  My full view file is:

```
<select>
   <script>
     var sel = document.getElementById('{{name}}');
     var opt = document.createElement("option");
     sel.add(opt);
     var n = {{!sorted(choices)}};
     n.forEach(function(n) {
        var opt = document.createElement("option");
        opt.value = n;
        opt.text = n;
        sel.add(opt);
     });
   </script>
  </select>
```

In order to post the question, I narrowed it down to the following code by removing my variables so that it can be simply replicated.

In my simple template view I have the following:
`var y = "{{!'For any x<1'}}";`

I expected the JavaScript variable y to have the value y='For any x<1'.  Using inspect, what bottle produced was:
`var y = "For any x&lt;1";`

When I run bottle --version I get
`Bottle 0.13-dev`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this fix it?

```
var y = "{{!'For any x<1' | safe}}";
```

Comment: I believe safe is only used in Django.  This is Bottle (pypi bottlepy).

When I try safe it says: `NameError: name 'safe' is not defined`

Comment: Bottle uses `jinja2` for templating. `safe` is a `jinja2` keyword, not sure why it isn't working in your case. https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#html-escaping

Comment: ah... let me check my implementation.   Thank you so much... I'll respond in 24 hours

Comment: Just a wild guess: maybe a missing import? Or you need to fully qualify `safe`? Good luck

Comment: By trying to use safe I figured out my environment was not set up correctly.